# How do I add the MHDD program to Hiren's BootCD?

Tags: hard-drive-recovery, hiren, boot-cd

How do I add [MHDD](http://hddguru.com/software/2005.10.02-MHDD/) to Hiren's BootCD so that I can try to repair my hard drive?

Comment: What? What do area51 or angle brackets have to do with anything? Please edit your question so that it makes sense.

Comment: Did you mean to copy part of [this comment on MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100369/why-is-my-stack-exchange-code-formatting-considered-wrong#comment254993_100375) into your question?

Answer (score 1):

As listed on the [Hiren's BootCD site](http://www.hiren.info/pages/bootcd), MHDD 4.6 is included under DOS Programs > Hard Disk Tools already:

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]